# Android If user enters the uppercase also it should be in lowercase

Tags: android-edittext

IF user enters the characters in uppercase also it should display in lowercase only
Regards,
Nikhilreddy

Comment: Do you mean: How to turn any text entered in a `TextView` into lowercase?

Comment: Whoalla!!! The whole question without even a single question mark. Are you really asking for help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String s = textView.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
```

Comment: While the question was really badly worded, it's nice to see someone providing an answer.  It was obvious what the original poster was asking for, they probably just had trouble expressing it in English!